# Android Layout change causes type-error

Tags: android

I am trying to change a working Android App from a 1 column layout to a 2 column layout.

When I do this, I get an execution error on my MainActivity.java, specifically in this line here:

```
ImageView picView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.picture);
```

The error states:

```
android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView
```

From this I understand that `findViewById(R.id.picture)` returns a `TextView`. But this does make sense to me. It is clearly defined as an ImageView in my `activity_main.xlm`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:baselineAligned="false">
    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/capture_btn"
        android:text="@string/capture"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/pick_btn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/pick"
        android:onClick="onClick" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/picture"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/pic_border" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Note: the same App works just find with the below (1 column) `activity_main.xlm`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<Button
android:id="@+id/capture_btn"
android:text="@string/capture"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
<Button
android:id="@+id/pick_btn"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/pick"
android:onClick="onClick" />
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/picture"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:contentDescription="@string/picture"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:background="@drawable/pic_border" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I face this error multiple times after changing xml. Did you clean the project and run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean your Project then run it again.